# Does a type inherited by restriction inherits minOccurs and maxOccurs for its elements?

Tags: inheritance, xsd

Here is a schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="Base">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="opt" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="D1a">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="Base">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="opt" maxOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="D1b">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="Base">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="opt" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="D1c">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="Base">
            <xs:sequence>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Visual Studio validates the shema without errors. But XMLSpy says that *D1a* is invalid because `maxOccurs` shoudn't be less than `minOccurs`. It's seems that Visual Studio thinks that `minOccurs` is inherited from *Base* and equals 0. But XMLSpy thinks that `minOccurs` shouldn't be inherited from *Base* and is equals 1 (default value).

Which behavior conforms to XSD specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLSpy is right.

According to XSD spec, when you restrict a complexType, you must redefine the element content model **completely anew**, but that new definition must comply with the old one.

No specific settings are inherited from how the base type was defined (in fact, you may even define the same content model using different constructs).

But by its own, the definition of `D1a` is erroneous.
In the declaration of the `opt` element you miss the `minOccurs` attribute.
But it does exist and its value by default is 1.
So, it is greater than the `maxOccurs` you have specified, which is nonsense of course. Visual Studio thinks wrong!

Comment: Could you point out the XSD spec text for this explanation? I am trying to figure out whether a ref="" element will inherit minOccurs/maxOccurs attributes or start anew. Hard to find a reference.

Comment: XSD 1.0, Sect 3.3.2, see description of {min occurs} property: "The ·actual value· of the minOccurs [attribute], if present, otherwise 1." It's not said in the specification, that minOccurs must be inherited from the base type. I can't find an explicit indication of the fact that the type derived by restriction is completely anew. But also I can't find any statements that complex types must inherit something from the restricted type. Intuitively I can understand, that the type derived by restriction is a new type, which just conforms to the restricted type and doesn't inherit anything from it.

Comment: I forget to note that it is a Part 1 of the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/ In other words, the specification says that `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` are equal to 1 by default. And the spec doesn't state anything about inheritance of these attributes.